# SQL Server 2008 : pivoting on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Need help with the pivot clause in SQL Server 2008. I have a table with this info:

I have a table with 9 columns: `ID`, `Period_1` to `Period_4` as dates (i.e. 2013-04, 2013-07, etc.) and `Amount_1` to `Amount_4` (i.e. 30, 40, etc.). I want all the distinct dates from `Period_1` to `Period_4` as column names and then pivot `Amount_1` corresponding to `Period_1`, `Amount_2` corresponding to `Period_2`, `Amount_3` corresponding to `Period_3` and `Amount_4` corresponding to `Period_4` as row values.

This is my T-SQL that I came up with for the moment:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
,@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ans)
        FROM (
            SELECT Period_1 AS ans
            FROM Booking

            UNION

            SELECT Period_2 AS ans
            FROM Booking

            UNION

            SELECT Period_3 AS ans
            FROM Booking

            UNION

            SELECT Period_4 AS ans
            FROM Booking
            ) a
        FOR XML PATH('')
            ,TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT Id ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select Id, Period_1, Amount_1, Period_2, Amount_2
            from Booking
         ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(Amount_1)
            for Period_1 in (' + @cols + ')

        ) p 
(
            max(Amount_2)
            for Period_2 in (' + @cols + ')

        ) p

        '

EXECUTE (@query)
```

and I get the ERROR:

> Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   The column name "2013-10   " specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the  existing column name in the PIVOT argument.

Is there any way to do a pivot query on multiple columns containing same values? Please write respond with an example on how to do it.

I appreciate any kind of help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your problem is your data is not normalized, having columns with `Period_1`, `Amount_1`, `Period_2`, `Amount_2` etc makes it incredibly difficult to query your data.  My first suggestion would be to consider fixing your table structure to something similar to the following:

```
create table booking
(
  id int,
  period datetime,
  amount decimal(10, 5)
);
```

This will allow you to have multiple periods and amounts for each id.  There are other ways to design this but this should give you an idea on how to fix your current structure.

If you are unable to fix your structure then I would suggest applying an UNPIVOT and then a PIVOT to your existing table.  The UNPIVOT will convert the multiple columns of data into multiple rows, then you can apply the PIVOT to the amounts to get the final result.

The basic syntax of the UNPIVOT will be the following. I used CROSS APPLY with a UNION ALL because we need to unpivot the Period and the Amount at the same time:

```
select id, 
  convert(varchar(7), period, 120) period,
  amount
from
(
  select id, 
    period_1, period_2, period_3, period_4,
    amount_1, amount_2, amount_3, amount_4
  from booking
) d
cross apply
(
  select period_1, amount_1 union all
  select period_2, amount_2 union all
  select period_3, amount_3 union all
  select period_4, amount_4
) c (period, amount);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba59f/13). This gives you data in the format:

```
| ID |  PERIOD | AMOUNT |
-------------------------
|  1 | 2013-01 |     30 |
|  1 | 2013-04 |     40 |
|  1 | 2013-07 |     50 |
|  1 | 2013-10 |     60 |
```

Once the data is in this format, you can apply the PIVOT function to the values in the `Period` column:

```
select id,
  [2013-01], [2013-04], [2013-05],
  [2013-07], [2013-08], [2013-10],
  [2013-11]
from
(
  select id, 
    convert(varchar(7), period, 120) period,
    amount
  from
  (
    select id, 
      period_1, period_2, period_3, period_4,
      amount_1, amount_2, amount_3, amount_4
    from booking
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select period_1, amount_1 union all
    select period_2, amount_2 union all
    select period_3, amount_3 union all
    select period_4, amount_4
  ) c (period, amount)
) src
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for period in ([2013-01], [2013-04], [2013-05],
                 [2013-07], [2013-08], [2013-10],
                 [2013-11])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba59f/14).  Of course the above will work great, if you know the values ahead of time. But if you don't then you will want to look at using dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(period) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select convert(varchar(7), period_1, 120) period, period_1 dt 
                      from booking union all
                      select convert(varchar(7), period_2, 120) period, period_2 dt
                      from booking union all
                      select convert(varchar(7), period_3, 120) period, period_3 dt
                      from booking union all
                      select convert(varchar(7), period_4, 120) period, period_4
                      from booking
                    ) d
                    group by period, dt
                    order by dt
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' 
            from
            (
              select id, 
                convert(varchar(7), period, 120) period,
                amount
              from
              (
                select id, 
                  period_1, period_2, period_3, period_4,
                  amount_1, amount_2, amount_3, amount_4
                from booking
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                select period_1, amount_1 union all
                select period_2, amount_2 union all
                select period_3, amount_3 union all
                select period_4, amount_4
              ) c (period, amount)
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                sum(amount)
                for period in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba59f/16).  These queries will give a result similar to:

```
| ID | 2013-01 | 2013-04 | 2013-05 | 2013-07 | 2013-08 | 2013-10 | 2013-11 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     105 |      40 |      86 |      50 |     120 |      60 |      65 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to append something to your field name and create one `@cols` variable for each value you're using, ie:

```
SELECT @cols1 = STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ans)
        FROM (SELECT '1_'+CAST(Period_1  AS VARCHAR(12)) AS ans
              FROM #test
              UNION
              SELECT '1_'+CAST(Period_2  AS VARCHAR(12)) AS ans
              FROM #test
            ) a
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'')
        ,@cols2 = STUFF((
                SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ans)
                FROM (SELECT '2_'+CAST(Period_1 AS VARCHAR(12)) AS ans
                      FROM #test
                      UNION
                      SELECT '2_'+CAST(Period_2 AS VARCHAR(12)) AS ans
                      FROM #test
                    ) a
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'')
```

And then reference the appropriate variable when pivoting, you'll have to add to the field names there too:

```
(
    max(Amount_1)
    for '1_'+CAST(Period_1 AS VARCHAR(12)) in (' + @cols1 + ')

) p
```

There might be a more clever way to do that, but I'm not aware of one.